# Как отсортировать элементы в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть записи в БД такого вида:

```
INSERT INTO `tokens` (`id`, `ticker`, `symbol`, `price`, `f_long`, `f_short`, `s_long`, `s_short`, `volume_5m`, `volatility`) VALUES
(22, 'AXS', 'AXSUSDT', 29.74, '30.38000;6957;211353;2.2;08.05.2022 16:46:33;0', '29.00000;11837;343273;2.4;08.05.2022 16:34:34;0', '29.96000000;3685.37000000;110413;0.8;08.05.2022 16:47:39;0', '29.54000000;4505.01000000;133077;0.6;08.05.2022 16:44:33;0', '7834.94000000;233522.11020000', 0.57),
(23, 'BAKE', 'BAKEUSDT', 0.5101, '', '', '', '', '40769.10000000;20803.43380000', 0.39),
(24, 'BAL', 'BALUSDT', 12.725, '', '', '', '', '253.24000000;3219.11980000', 0.16),
(25, 'BAND', 'BANDUSDT', 2.7832, '', '', '', '', '857.90000000;2390.26030000', 0.32),
(26, 'BAT', 'BATUSDT', 0.5528, '', '', '', '0.54920000;299874.00000000;164690;0.5;08.05.2022 16:46:42;0', '20586.00000000;11396.99290000', 0.31),
```

Таким образом я раскладываю записи по массивам:

```
$query_select = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `tokens` ORDER BY `f_long` DESC, `f_short` DESC, `s_long` DESC, `s_short` DESC, `id`");

$count = 0;

while ($select = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select))
{ $coins[$count]['ticker'] = $select['ticker']; 
$coins[$count]['symbol'] = $select['symbol']; 
$coins[$count]['price'] = $select['price']; 
$coins[$count]['f_long'] = $select['f_long']; 
$coins[$count]['f_short'] = $select['f_short']; 
$coins[$count]['s_long'] = $select['s_long']; 
$coins[$count]['s_short'] = $select['s_short']; 
$coins[$count]['volume_5m'] = $select['volume_5m']; 

    $count++;
}
```

Первым шагом мне необходимо отформатировать только те записи, где есть данные в полях `f_long`, `f_short`, `s_long`, `s_short`, то есть отсортировать в начало те элементы, в которых есть данные хотя бы в одном из столбцов.
Вторым шагом я не пойму, как мне сортировать данные внутри этих полей. Там данные такого вида разделенные через точку с запятой (;)

> 0.0019350;103368480;200018;0.8;11.04.2022 08:50:03;0

Потом через explode я делю эти параметры и они у меня получаются отдельно и я их вывожу на экран. Но теперь стоит задача, отсортировать массив $coins по 4 значению в этой записи, в данном случае это 0.8.

Как отсортировать таким способом, чтобы первыми элементами были значения, в полях `f_long`, `f_short`, `s_long`, `s_short` если содержится хоть какая-то информация (не пустое) и чтобы они были отсортированы по 4-му значению этих записей (0.0019350;103368480;200018;**0.8**;11.04.2022 08:50:03;0) по убыванию.

Пробую делать так:

```
    usort($coins, function ($a, $b) {
      $a = explode(';',$a['f_long']);
      $b = explode(';',$b['f_long']);
      if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
        return 0;
      }
      return $a[2] < $b[2] ? 1:-1;
    });
```

Получаю вроде сортировку начиная с столбца f_long правильно, но так же выдаются ошибки **Warning: Undefined array key 2 in /var/www/domains/site.ru/index.php on line 62** что указывает на строчку if ($a[2] == $b[2])

Но таким образом, я сортирую только поля этого столбца, а мне нужно собрать со всех 4-х столбцов (`f_long` `f_short` `s_long` `s_short`) и их выстроить по убыванию 4-ого значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уверен, что сортировку будет проще делать прямо в sql запросе. Сортировать по значению внутри строки можно с использованием функции `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. Если я правильно понял задание, то запрос будет примерно такой

```sql
SELECT * FROM `tokens`
ORDER BY
f_long != '' || f_short != '' || s_long != '' || s_short DESC,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(f_long,';',4) DESC,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(f_short,';',4) DESC,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(s_long,';',4) DESC,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(s_short,';',4) DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Но.. единственное, я не понимаю его порядок сортировки. Он сортировал всё по полям, но по значениям почему-то не хочет, если даже менять последний параметр в SUBSTRING_INDEX, то сортировка остаётся точно такой-же, как-будто он не отрабатывает эту функцию

Comment: Порядок соответствует порядку в ORDER BY, т.е. сначала идут записи у которых хотя бы одно поле из указанных не пустое, потом сортируются по 4-му значению в f_long и т.д., и если вы меняете последний параметр SUBSTRING_INDEX например у f_short нужно учитывать, что значения уже отсортированы по f_long и порядок записей изменится только там, где значения в f_long будут одинаковыми